# Copy data from a selected view in a fieldcollection field

Tags: views, entities

I have content_type TYPE1 content with two fields:

- **fiedl_1** is a viewfield type that allows me to display a view inside a node.
- **fiedl_2** is fieldcollection type.

Is it possible to copy the rows resulting from the view into my fielcollection?

Thanks a lot

Comment: What do you mean by copy? Are you wanting to move the view field into your field collection, or are you wanting to copy the data in the view into different fields into the field collection?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help @Shawn Conn.
Yes, I want to copy the data returned by the view in my field collection.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible but you're going to have to do some hoop jumping to make it happen:

- Determine *when* this copy action will happen (e.g. `hook_entity_update` trigger).
- Programmatically retrieve the View's data (e.g. via `Views::getView()` /  `views_get_view()` depending on your Drupal version)
- Parse the view data an update the update relevant node fields with the view data. (which will also depend on your Drupal version).

Comment: Thanks a lot @Shawn Conn. I use Drupal 7. So, this copy action will happen after save the node, because the view is displayed only after saving the node.